# Como eu faço para mostrar os números entrados errados?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Nesse código eu gostaria que se o aluno digitar alguma nota errada, o programa responda qual são as notas que estão erradas. Mas baseado no que eu fiz só aparece a primeira nota.

Também gostaria que ao digitar as notas corretas apareça se foi aprovado ou não.

```
n1 = int(input('digite nota 1: '))
n2 = int(input('digite nota 2: '))
media = (n1 + n2)/2
if n1 > 10:
  print('{} não é uma nota válida!'.format(n1))
elif n2 > 10:
  print('{} não é uma nota válida!'.format(n2))
elif media >= 7 and media<=10:
  print('Você foi aprovado com média {}'.format(media))
elif media < 7 and media<=10:
  print('Você foi reprovado com média {}'.format(media))
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Está abusando do `elif`. Não é porque tem várias condições que tudo deve ser agrupada. Tem que fazer isso de acordo com a necessidade.

A validação de cada nota deve ser independente, não faz sentido colocar um `elif` ali, a não ser para complicar o código, até poderia de uma outra forma mas complica muito o código e ele ficaria menos legível. O mais correto quando um dado inválido é entrado é encerrar. Se fosse em uma função bastaria usar um `return`, se fosse em um *loop*, poderia usar um `continue` ou até um `break` em algumas situações. Como está no *script* puro deve sair com `exit()`.

A média só deve ser calculada quando tem dados válidos e continuou a execução.

N]ao é necessário verificar se a média é até 10 porque se os dados estão válidos ela foi calculada até o limite correto.

E finalmente não precisa verificar nada na reprovação porque é o oposto da aprovação, basta um `else` simples.

```
import sys

n1 = int(input('digite nota 1: '))
n2 = int(input('digite nota 2: '))
if n1 > 10:
    print('{} não é uma nota válida!'.format(n1))
    sys.exit(0)
if n2 > 10:
    print('{} não é uma nota válida!'.format(n2))
    sys.exit(0)
media = (n1 + n2) / 2
if media >= 7:
    print('Você foi aprovado com média {}'.format(media))
else:
    print('Você foi reprovado com média {}'.format(media))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KCbpeg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ValidateGradepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ValidateGrade.py).

Dá para fazer do jeito que estava fazendo sem forçar a saída? Dá, mas a lógica ficaria confusa demais para uma pessoa experiente, imagina para uma pessoa começando. E correria o risco de aprender de um jeito confuso para o resto da vida. Fora que seria menos eficiente, ainda que não seja algo relevante para esse caso poderia ser um dia e já acostuma fazer mais correto.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode construir uma função capaz de ler as notas, tratá-las conforme as regras definidas, exibir os eventuais erros e só retornar se a nota digitada estiver válida, veja só:

```
def obter_nota_aluno(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            # Lê a nota
            n = input(msg)

            # Converte e verifica se a nota é um inteiro válido
            n = int(n) 

            # Verifica se a nota está dentro da faixa válida
            if (n < 0) or (n > 10):
                raise ValueError()

            # Retorna nota
            return n
        except ValueError:
            # Exibe o erro
            print(f'{n} não é uma nota válida, tente novamente.')

n1 = obter_nota_aluno('digite nota 1: ')
n2 = obter_nota_aluno('digite nota 2: ')

media = (n1 + n2) / 2

if media >= 7:
    print(f'Você foi APROVADO com média {media}')
else:
    print(f'Você foi REPROVADO com média {media}')
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BossyFickleVisitors)